# Getting latitude and longitude

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

Guys plz tell why this code showning No provider available

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if (loc != null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Provider" + provider + " has been selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    tv.setText("No provider Available");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to define the permissions in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation